# Which of the Polity novels feature the character Sniper?

Tags: episode-identification, polity-universe

I recently stumbled upon *The Skinner* by Neal Asher and absolutely enjoy the character of Sniper!

I tried to find out where else Sniper may appear, but couldn't find any character lists that helped me.

What other *Polity* novels feature Sniper in them?

Comment: To the close voters: this is a request to identify a (rather small) list of works containing a specific character; it's not an endless list and is not seeking recommendations. The entire Polity Universe spans 16 works; OP is looking for a subset of that.

Comment: @SQB Size doesn't matter. There could then be up to 16 separate answers that all have equal value.

Comment: @Skooba no, answers should list all of them, 16 at most. The problem is with unbounded list, like "all books with robots". I'm on mobile, so I'm not providing a link, but the policy allows for restricted lists like this one.

Comment: @SQB I think you may be thinking of [this policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/98028).

Comment: @Jenayah indeed I am.

Answer (score 3):

The Skinner, The Voyage of the Sable Keech, and Orbus, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Sniper features in the Novel [Orbus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6462796-orbus)
A brief description from Goodreads.

> In charge of an old cargo spaceship, the Old Captain Orbus flees a violent and sadistic past, but he doesn't know that the lethal war drone, Sniper, is a stowaway, and that the past is rapidly catching up with him.